# Trigger an API endpoint when ever a file stored in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I need to trigger an API endpoint when a new file or existing file modified in the Azure Blob storage.
How can I achieve this

Comment: Check this.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage#add-blob-storage-trigger

Answer (score 0):

If it for using the same code in the Web API. You could make a backgroundservice in the API project there will listen for an event.

Or a service there have the responsibility to listen, and send the information to the endpoint.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Then there are some documentation here on how Azure can help you with trigger things.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Azure Logic App to do this.  It can be triggered when a blob is added/changed and then use the HTTP action to call the api.